# sails:how to read exact data from excel file having extention with xls to json

Tags: json, node.js, excel, sails.js

I'm trying to read xls  file data into json format and want to upload that data into elastic-search. i'm using `xlsjs` node-module for reading xls file.

```
 var XLS = require('xlsjs');
var workbook = XLS.readFile("sheet.xls");
```

This node module read whole excel file into json format.but i need only the  data which i entered into xls file.

Is this possible to read exact data from xls to json format.

Thanks in advance.